# Highlight row in one react table is highlighting the same row in a second one on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have two react tables on the same page with different data. I have the option for the user to select multiple rows in both tables. The problem I am experiencing, is that if they select any row in one table, it selects the  same row in the other table. How do I make it so on select it only styles the table that was selected?

Here is the `getTrProps` for the first table.

```js
<ReactTable
    data={this.state.table1state}
    columns={columnNames}
    showPagination={false}
    minRows={0}
    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
            return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                    if (this.state.selectedOpp.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0) {
                        var selectedOpp = this.state.selectedOpp;
                        selectedOpp.splice(selectedOpp.indexOf(rowInfo.index), 1);
                        this.setState({ selectedOpp: selectedOpp });
                    } else {
                        var selectedOpp = this.state.selected;
                        selectedOpp.push(rowInfo.index);
                        this.setState({ selectedOpp: selectedOpp });
                    }

                },
                style: {
                    background: this.state.selectedOpp.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                    color: this.state.selectedOpp.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }}
/>
```

And here is for the second. Exactly the same except I am using a different state to store the selected rows in, which doesn't fix the problem.

```js
<ReactTable
    data={this.state.table2state}
    columns={columnNames}
    showPagination={false}
    minRows={0}
    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
            return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                    if (this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0) {
                        var selected = this.state.selected;
                        selected.splice(selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index), 1);
                        this.setState({ selected: selected });
                    } else {
                        var selected = this.state.selected;
                        selected.push(rowInfo.index);
                        this.setState({ selected: selected });
                    }

                },
                style: {
                    background: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                    color: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }}
/>
```

Any way to specify more, like only style this specific table that this row is part of rather than that row index of all tables?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you mapping both the tables to the same state?

Comment: @AakashVerma like the same data state? both populated with data from different states. or what do you mean?

Comment: oh alright, that's what I wanted to know whether you have both tables pointing to the same state variables. Can you show me the parent to these two tables?

Comment: I believe it's the same table component which is being passed different props. I don't know how you are calling getTrProps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing this by not using the row index (rowInfo.index). Since the indexes are shared between tables, seemed to highlight both. So, instead I used the _id of the row data as follows:

```js
<ReactTable
    data={this.state.table2state}
    columns={columnNames}
    showPagination={false}
    minRows={0}
    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
            return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                    if (this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.original._id) >= 0) {
                        var selected = this.state.selected;
                        selected.splice(selected.indexOf(rowInfo.original._id), 1);
                        this.setState({ selected: selected });
                    } else {
                        var selected = this.state.selected;
                        selected.push(rowInfo.original._id);
                        this.setState({ selected: selected });
                    }

                },
                style: {
                    background: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.original._id) >= 0 ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                    color: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.original._id) >= 0 ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }}
/>
```

This way each selection array has the id of the data in the row instead of just which row it is. Idk if you even need multiple selection arrays, prob dont, but still prob good to have them.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting `this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.original._id)` as `-1` (index not existing)

Answer (score 1):

They are mapped to the same state of their container component. You might be passing different state variables for data but the `selected` state variable is the same for both React tables and so with the context being bound in the arrow functions, it's using the same parent state variable `selected`.

Try having different `selected` arrays for both the React tables.

Also, reduce code redundancy

```
<ReactTable
    key="table1"
    data={this.state.table2state}
    columns={columnNames}
    showPagination={false}
    minRows={0}
    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => { 
    const selected = this.state.selectedTable1;
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
            return {
                onClick: (e) => {
                    if (this.state.selectedTable1.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0) {
                        selected.splice(selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index), 1);
                    } else {
                        selected.push(rowInfo.index);
                    }
                    this.setState({ selectedTable1: selected });
                },
                style: {
                    background: this.state.selectedTable1.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                    color: this.state.selectedTable1.indexOf(rowInfo.index) >= 0 ? 'white' : 'black'
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }
}
/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I do currently have the background and color going to 2 different states, but it does not seem to matter.